# Multiple Disks during Suse Linux Enterprise Server 11 installation

Tags: partition, sles, sles11

I am installing  SLES11 on my server (8  x 1TB disks), and I am installing the Xen Hypervisor mode(but I guess the is irrelevant to my question).

I have a question how to setup my disks paritions (I want to use the 8 disk as JBOD mode --i.e, simply mount them for usage, NO any RAID mechanism). I can't figure out how to setup the "Expert Partitioner" right now, can someone give me a help? http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxinfo/v3r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/liaai/multipath/liaaiiscsimultisles.htm

how should I play with that step to get what I want?

Answer (score 1):

You could set up a logical volume (LVM).  In yast (type yast command as root), go to **System > Partitioner** and select **Volume Management**.

Comment: LVM is really good for this. It's a bit hard to figure out from the Expert screen, but it can be done.